# OpenCart Set language through URL

Tags: javascript, php, menu, opencart

When I select my language from the dropdown flag the opencart translates to the new language and I get directed to the index page.

I want to stay on the current page.

I found an article for this issue but I couldn`t make it work.
[Link](http://perfectcod.es/2013/07/05/opencart-set-language-through-url/)

This is my current code from catalog/controller/module/language.php

```js
<?php if (count($languages) > 1) { ?>
<!-- Language -->
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="language_form">
 <div class="dropdown">
  <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
  <?php if ($language['code'] == $code) { ?>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $language['name']; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
    <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('input[name=\'code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $language['code']; ?>'); $('#language_form').submit();"><?php echo $language['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <input type="hidden" name="code" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirect; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is your OpenCart version?

Comment: Opencart 2.3.0.2

Comment: There is no `catalog/controller/module/language.php` in OpenCart 2.3.0.2 by default. Are you using a module?

Comment: what is the value of $redirect ?